# get last 6 characters of a match (javascript regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am trying to parse txt files with js + regex and my problem is as follows:

I have multiple txt files, and inside each one I need to search for an Id, made by 6 characters (numb + letters)

this is the string inside one of those files:

```
**IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('codice sito',$,IFCTEXT('I013FR'),$);**
```

I need to extract the **I013FR** only, and so far the closest js-regex I wrote is:

```
(codice sito',\$,IFCTEXT\('[a-zA-Z\d]{6})
```

using that, I get in return:

```
codice sito',$,IFCTEXT('I372TO
```

now I need to "add something" at the end of the regex, in order to only take the last 6 characters from the match.

Is that possible? am I on the right way? or maybe there is another better way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! So you're basically parsing code here? Regex isn't suitable for parsing program source code. Can you offer a bit more context--is this a one-off thing with a clear structure to the `IFCTEXT` bit, or can it be arbitrarily complex? `s.match(/'codice sito',\$,IFCTEXT\('([^']+)'\)/)` should work on this though.

Comment: Just modify your [capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)

Comment: Hi, aitenlabs!  Welcome to SO!  You say you want "the last 6 characters", your regex is `[a-zA-Z\d]{6}`, doesn't the `{6}` mean the last six characters?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger No it doesn't

Comment: thank you all for the comments, the answer below from Mikhail solved the issue! ;D 

to give you a bit of context, basically I have like 5.000 files, which are 3D models basically. I already did something to convert those files in .txt in one shot. Now I need to extract infos from all of those files, and put those info in a db-like table (csv, json, xls (it doesn't matter)) and to extract those infos I am trying to use regex because the string patterns are always the same. The one you see above it's just the first "data" to extract, but there are many more left. thanks again for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the sequence of symbols, you need to put it in parenthesis. This pattern is called a "capturing group". [Read more](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)

```
/codice sito',\$,IFCTEXT\('([a-zA-Z\d]{6})/g
```

And then you can get your id using [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method.

```
const str = "**IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('codice sito',$,IFCTEXT('I013FR'),$);**";
const regex = /codice sito',\$,IFCTEXT\('([a-zA-Z\d]{6})/g;

const id = regex.exec(str)[1];
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, that clarifies and solves my problem :D